# Ignore a line in batch file from powershell?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Suppose i have the following batch file, named `openPS.bat`:

```
@echo off

SET psFile="%1"

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :error
GOTO :end
:error
echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo Failed!

EXIT /B %ErrorLevel%
:end
echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo Success!
```

This batch file is used to run a powershell script in a CMD console:

> C:> openPS.bat script.ps1

the script.ps1 runs multiple times by a wrapper, so everytime it runs successfully, it outputs `exit code 0`

[image: exit code 0]

Can i somehow ignore this line in openPS.bat via powershell?

```
EXIT /B %ErrorLevel%
:end
echo Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
echo Success!
```

i know i can `REM` it but i need to output one success message after all loops of the script.ps1 are completed. so it has to remain and I found no way to suppress all those exit code 0's. if i use `out-null` in powershell script, i lose all other output, so `out-null` is not an option.

Comment: How do you intend to handle errors (exit code <> 0)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thats why out-null didnt work for me because it would ignore errors. and the only option i see is to somehow ignore that success line directly from batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking and showing "Success!" for each iteration, use the wrapper script to indicate completion.  The screen will show only the failures and completion message.

You can also use a variable in the wrapper script to keep track of the return values, a simple sum will work, and test it for `0` when execution of all of the iterations is complete. Then display success or failure.

```
@echo off

SET psFile="%1"

Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File %psFile% %2 %3 %4 %5

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :error
GOTO :end
:error
echo Exit Code: %errorlevel%
echo Failed!

:end
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

Comment: now that i think baout it...there is no need to indicate success, as long as there is a error code retuned back (0 or 1)